# Android Relative Layout multiple screen problems

Tags: android, android-layout, screen, android-relativelayout

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMAiR.png 
**this is my screenshot of the layout** 
I used Relativelayout when designing the layout and imageButtons, TextViews, Scroll view in my layout which are sized with using dp and sp values. In the screenshot I showed where should the scroll view and textview should actually be placed, when I place them it works ok but the problem comes when trying on other screens.
 I made about 9 diffrent layouts wheter it be qualifiers such as layout-swdp or layout-normal to work on multiple screen, but when I create new virtual device's with different screen sizes, resolution sometimes the layout is placed as I wanted and sometimes not. It seems like at the moment I need to create all the screen size,resolution and density combinations to achive what I want but this doesn't seem normal to me, I think it would take around 30 different layout for different combinations at total to place the scroll view and textview to where I want.
 The backgroundimage I am using is set to the relative layouts background property. The thing I am asking is what can I do to solve my problem, is it normal to create around 30 different layouts for different screen combinations ? or am I approaching the problem in a wrong way ? or maybe the mistake was in the begining by placing the spots on the background image(using photoshop) where the textviews and scrollview will be placed ?
any advice would be appreciated

Comment: You can't use fixed values in this case, no matter how much layout you created, there will always a device that you didn't cover yet. So I suggest you should use DisplayMetrics and calculate the view position by code.

Comment: can you please give me an example, I am new to android, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    /**
    * 
    * @param view
    * @param wantedTop wanted space in original image (in px)
    * @param originBgSize if images in drawble-mdpi, drawable-hdpi,... have same ratio, you can use any size of them 
    */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void calSize(View view, int wantedTop, Point originBgSize) { 
    double imageH = originBgSize.y;
    // get your screen size in pixel
    Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
      size.x = d.getWidth();
      size.y = d.getHeight();
    }
    else {
      d.getSize(size);
    }
    double ratioH = size.y / imageH; 
    int convertedTop = (int) (wantedTop * ratioH);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    if (params instanceof MarginLayoutParams) {
      ((MarginLayoutParams) params).topMargin = convertedTop;
      view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
    }
```

Then in `OnCreated`:

```
    View tv = null;// your text view here;
    // I assume that your image dimension is 720x1014, and the top position you want is 55px
    Point oriSize = new Point(720, 1024); 
    calSize(tv, 55, oriSize);
```

Hope this works;

Comment: ill give it a try tonight, so as far as i understood if my background image is 720x1024 with using this method it will for example, place my scroll view on 55th pixel from top independent from screen density, resolution and size? it will put the view to cordiantes it uses from the bacground image's resolution whether the background be stretched or not ?

Comment: 55px it's the y-axis position you want to place your textview in your origin image.( 55 pixels from top edge)